# Send JSON values to PHP not woking

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I tried to use Ajax using JQuery but my code is not working.

JQuery Code:

```
var prvdatas = {
            "prvpname": "<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>",
            "prvlogname": "<?php echo $_SESSION['usernamelg']; ?>",
            "prvtype": "get",
            "prvcat": "post"
            };
    var  aaaa = JSON.stringify(prvdatas);
       $.ajax({
         url : "/php/privacy.php",
         type: "POST",
         data : aaaa,
         success: function(response){
            $('#prvstatus').html(response);
            $('.prvmodal *').prop("disabled", false);
         }
    });
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $prvpname = $_POST['prvpname'];
    $prvlogname = $_POST['prvlogname'];
    $prvtype = $_POST['prvtype'];
    $prvcat = $_POST['prvcat'];
    $prvnum = $_POST['prvnum'];
    $prvval = $_POST['prvval'];

    echo $prvpname . $prvlogname . $prvtype . $prvcat . $prvnum . $prvval;  
?>
```

How to solve this problem. If I use `echo "sometext";` it is working fine in PHP.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: just remove **JSON.stringify(prvdatas)** and simply let **aaaa=prvdatas** because the posted data should be an object not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line `JSON.stringify(prvdatas). and`prvdatas` set in data:prvdatas

following code:

```
         var prvdatas = {
                "prvpname": "<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>",
                "prvlogname": "<?php echo $_SESSION['usernamelg']; ?>",
                "prvtype": "get",
                "prvcat": "post"
                };

           $.ajax({
             url : "/php/privacy.php",
             type: "POST",
             data : prvdatas,
             success: function(response){
                $('#prvstatus').html(response);
                $('.prvmodal *').prop("disabled", false);
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

just replace :

```
data : aaaa,
```

with :

```
 data: {
   prvpname: "<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>",
   prvlogname: "<?php echo $_SESSION['usernamelg']; ?>",
   prvtype: "get",
   prvcat: "post"
 }
```

your code will be like without any extra variables :

```
$.ajax({
   url : "/php/privacy.php",
   type: "POST",
   data : {
       prvpname: "<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>",
       prvlogname: "<?php echo $_SESSION['usernamelg']; ?>",
       prvtype: "get",
       prvcat: "post"
   },
   success: function(response){
      $('#prvstatus').html(response);
      $('.prvmodal *').prop("disabled", false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `$_POST['prvnum']` and `$_POST['prvval']` are *undefined* in the `POST` request. Also, you don't have to convert your JavaScript object to string, directly use `prvdatas` in the AJAX request.

```
var prvdatas = {
    "prvpname": "<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>",
    "prvlogname": "<?php echo $_SESSION['usernamelg']; ?>",
    "prvtype": "get",
    "prvcat": "post",
    "prvnum": "SOMEVALUE",    
    "prvval": "SOMEVALUE"
};
$.ajax({
    url : "/php/privacy.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : prvdatas,
    success: function(response){
        $('#prvstatus').html(response);
        $('.prvmodal *').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```